# Microsoft Data Visualization (Chart) shows date as 1899-30-01

Tags: c#, datetime, mschart

Ok I've resolved already the problem. Must be double[] xvaluesTmp, and values are assigned: xvaluesTmp[0] = DateTime.Now.ToOADate() (as double), Now works perfect

---

I downloaded Microsoft Charts control (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll). 
To display hour, minute and seconds i have format:

```
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{HH}:{mm}:{ss}";
```

And it show rigth. But how looks format to display year-month-day ? I try from documentation: "D", "G", "M", "d", "y". It shows me date but always shows 1899-30-01 or 30 January 1899 etc. I pass to DataBinding DateTime.Now:

```
List<DateTime> xvaluesTmp = new List<DateTime>();
            xvaluesTmp.Add(DateTime.Now);
            xvaluesTmp.Add(new DateTime(2011, 3, 28));
...
this.chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xvaluesTmp, yvaluesTmp);
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: The example you gave is wrong, that should be "HH:mm:ss" without the curly braces.  Have you tried "yyyy-MM-dd"?  You ought to use CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, it display date as 1899:12:30. Where I should use CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat ? I pass values as List<DateTime>.

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok I've resolved already the problem. Must be double[] xvaluesTmp, and values are assigned: xvaluesTmp[0] = DateTime.Now.ToOADate() (as double), Now works perfect

Comment: Robert, may I suggest the _delete_ button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem for some time and have finally resolved it by:

Attaching to the customise event of the chart:

```
_chart.Customize += Remove_1899_Label;
```

And in the Remove_1899_Label event handler:

```
private void Remove_1899_Label(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart msChart = sender as Chart;

    foreach (var chartArea in msChart.ChartAreas)
    {
        foreach (var label in chartArea.AxisX.CustomLabels)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label.Text) && label.Text == "1899")
            {
                label.SetFieldValue("customLabel", true);
                label.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

N.B For some reason, changing the text of the label doesn't work unless you also set the private bool member variable named 'customLabel' of the Label to true. The implementation of the extension method 'SetFieldValue(string, object)' I got from here:
http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2013/06/c-how-to-set-or-get-value-of-a-private-or-internal-field-through-the-reflection/

However, I've included it below for completeness.

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
        //...
        // here are methods described in the post
        // http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/12/c-how-to-set-or-get-value-of-a-private-or-internal-property-through-the-reflection/
        //...

        private static FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(Type type, string fieldName)
        {
                FieldInfo fieldInfo;
                do
                {
                        fieldInfo = type.GetField(fieldName,
                                     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                        type = type.BaseType;
                }
                while (fieldInfo == null && type != null);
                return fieldInfo;
        }

        public static object GetFieldValue(this object obj, string fieldName)
        {
                if (obj == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
                Type objType = obj.GetType();
                FieldInfo fieldInfo = GetFieldInfo(objType, fieldName);
                if (fieldInfo == null)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fieldName",
                            string.Format("Couldn't find field {0} in type {1}", fieldName, objType.FullName));
                return fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
        }

        public static void SetFieldValue(this object obj, string fieldName, object val)
        {
                if (obj == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
                Type objType = obj.GetType();
                FieldInfo fieldInfo = GetFieldInfo(objType, fieldName);
                if (fieldInfo == null)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fieldName",
                            string.Format("Couldn't find field {0} in type {1}", fieldName, objType.FullName));
                fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, val);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit vague this question, but for anyone having a problem with 1899 date showing ensure that the ChartValueType is set to DateTime.

If ChartValueType is set to Time, then the 1899 date will show.

```
this.mainChart.ChartTypeSelected.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

then format the label to what you need

```
this.mainChart.ChartTypeSelected.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "mm:ss";
```